# How can I know all git changes using some GitHub command.?

Tags: git, pull-request

I am using

```bash
git status --porcelain -uall
```

It gives a result like this:

```bash
?? FOLDER1/FOLDERCHILD/ETC/FILE1.cs
```

From this, I want to remove `??` and keep the rest, but if I make some commits, then my Git changes will be 0 and this query won't work.

How can I retrieve all the file names/paths that have been committed in my branch?

I tried

```bash
git diff --name-only main...
```

This looks like a good option but it returns only the file names that are committed (reverse of above problem).

I don't want to use the GitHub API, only Git commands.

I want to know if there any command that can give me all of my Git changes:

- file path/name that I have commited in my branch
- file path/name that I have not committed and are present in unstaging as well as in staging area

I would like a similar result to what we get when we open a pull request.

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you're asking. For example, a "file that has been committed in your branch", do you mean "*changed* in my topic branch compared to the main branch"? Commits always include the entire repository. Or what's "unstaging"? Do you mean "working directory"? Git terminology is quite confusing. https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary is quite helpful for definitions.

Comment: In the title you are asking about a "GitHub command" and later you say that you don't want to use the GitHub API, that's confusing.

Comment: All files have been committed on your branch. Do you want to list all files _changed_ on your branches against master or main branch? How about just `git status`?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to simply get rid of the leading part using `sed`.

For instance, the bellow command gives you the list of files (without any further details):

```bash
$ git status --porcelain=v1 | sed -E 's/^.{2} //'
sources/data/f1.c
sources/data/f2.c
sources/data/f3.c
```

More details: Here, the `sed` command is used for replacing a specific pattern (in this case the regular expression `^.{2}`  which matches "the first two characters at the beginning of the line with a white space") with nothing.

An improved solution could be to merge the result of the `git status` and `git diff` commands in order to obtain the full list of edited files (no matter their status as long as they are tracked).

The command would look like this:

```bash
$ (git status --porcelain=v1 | sed -E 's/^.{2} //' && git diff --name-only main...) | sort | uniq
include/data.h
sources/data/f1.c
sources/data/f2.c
```